# Incompatible Class Declaration c++

Tags: c++, class, declaration

I have class `NumberArray` in `NumberArray.h`

```
class NumberArray
{
private:
  double *aPtr;
  int arraySize;

public:
  NumberArray(int size, double value);

  // ~NumberArray() { if (arraySize > 0) delete [ ] aPtr;}
  //commented out to avoid problems with the
  //default copy constructor
  void print() const; 
  void setValue(double value);
};
```

When I go to write the print function in NumberArray.cpp

```
void NumberArray::print()
{
  for (int index = 0; index < arraySize; index++)
    cout << aPtr[index] << "  ";
}
```

It gives me an error

> declaration is incompatible with "void NumberArray::print() const

Any thoughts where I might be going wrong on this?
The rest of the constructors and class functions work fine.

Comment: Cant see semicolon ';' at the end of statement  cout << aPtr[index] << "  "

Comment: `void print() const;` vs `void NumberArray::print()` -- can you spot the difference now? You declared a `const` function but implemented it as non-`const`. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Why you give the const specificator in your print function?

Comment: The code does include a ; at the end of the statement, just forgot to include it for some odd reason.

Comment: Charllie, I use const on pretty much any class function that I don't want changed just to be safe. Should I not be doing this? Is it extraneous and not needed?

Comment: Well it is really good behavior so keep it up :)

Comment: It's a good practice to declare as `const` any method that doesn't intend to change the object. The compiler can warn you if you break the contract. Changing the object in a method that is supposed to not have side effects (like `NumArray::print()`) can trigger bugs very difficult to find.

Answer (score 9):

You forgot to add the `const` qualifier (as well as a semicolon) to the signature of the definition of the function.

You have to do:

```
void NumberArray::print() const
{
  for (int index = 0; index < arraySize; index++)
    cout << aPtr[index] << "  ";
}
```

Comment: Was unaware that the definition needed the const outside of the class. Thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: @Jeffrey Dilley how else would the function signatures match?  There's quite a difference between a `const` and a non-`const` member function and a class can contain both with the same name (overloads).