# Declaration is incompatible after making the method constant

Tags: c++

I have declared two constant functions in a header file that pop an error when I try to define them in an implementation file.

I noticed that removing "const" from the declaration gets rid of the errors but it is required by the professor that the methods are constant in the header file.

```
//header file
#ifndef DEGREE_RVC_H
#define DEGREE_RVC_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class degree {
    public:
        degree();
        degree(double);
        degree(double, char);
        void setAll(double, char);
        void setTemp(double);
        void setScale(char);

        double getF() const;        
        double getC() const;

    private:
        double temp;
        char scale;
};

#endif
```

```
//implementation file

double degree::getC()
{
    if (scale == 'c') {
        return temp;
    }
    else return 5.0 / 9.0 * (temp - 32);
}

double degree ::getF()
{
    if (scale == 'f') {
        return temp;
    }
    else return temp * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32;
}
```

The getF and getC methods give me the same errors that refer me to the line they were declared in the header file, but the specific error is "declaration is incompatible with double degree::'methodname()' const"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incompatible Class Declaration c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729253/incompatible-class-declaration-c)

Answer (score 2):

Declarations and definitions need to match. Since you can't (and shouldn't) remove `const` from the declarations, add it to the definitions.

```
double degree::getC() const
{
    ...
}

double degree ::getF() const
{
    ...
}
```